# Dask replicate Pandas value counts on Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, bigdata

What I am trying to do is replicate panda's value counts + idxmax functions in dask, because I have a lot of data. Here is an example dataframe:

```
partner_num cust_id item_id revw_ratg_num   revw_dt item_qty
0   100 01  5   05/30/2000  0
0   100 03  5   05/30/2000  0
0   100 02  5   05/30/2000  0
1   200 13  4   04/01/2000  0
1   200 14  5   04/01/2000  1
2   200 22  2   04/01/2000  1
3   200 37  3   04/01/2000  1
9   300 92  1   03/24/2000  1
9   300 93  1   03/24/2000  1
9   300 94  1   03/24/2000  0
9   300 99  1   03/24/2000  0
6   300 91  2   03/24/2000  0

>>>df.head()
   partner_num  cust_id  item_id  revw_ratg_num     revw_dt  item_qty
0            0      100        1              5  05/30/2000         0
1            0      100        3              5  05/30/2000         0
2            0      100        2              5  05/30/2000         0
3            1      200       13              4  04/01/2000         0
4            1      200       14              5  04/01/2000         1
```

In pandas you could do it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("fake_data.txt", sep="\t")
df.groupby(["cust_id"]).item_qty.value_counts()

cust_id  item_qty
100      0           3
200      1           3
         0           1
300      0           3
         1           2
```

However, when you go to do the same thing in Dask, it fails, throwing an Attribute Error

```
df1 = dd.read_csv("fake_data.txt", sep="\t")
df1.groupby(["cust_id"]).item_qty.value_counts()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    df1.groupby(["cust_id"]).item_qty.value_counts()
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts''
```

What I really want to be able to do is to be able to get both the values, as well as their occurrence counts after a multi-column groupby in Dask. Any alternate solutions are acceptable, I just want to get the job done!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`value_counts` is not directly supported in the [dask API](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html) for dataframes.  Use `apply` to achieve your desired result.

Note that [`value_counts`](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html) is supported as a Series method.

```
>>> df1.groupby(['cust_id']).item_qty.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).compute()
cust_id   
100      0    3
200      1    3
         0    1
300      0    3
         1    2
Name: item_qty, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow thank you!! I knew something wasnt supported, I just didnt know where I was going wrong. +1 and accepted edit: cant +1 due to rep haha

Comment: Dask has been update and directly supports [value_counts](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html?highlight=value_counts#dask.dataframe.Series.value_counts)!