# pandas column filter slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to isolate groups of names in a data frame then count the number of entries in the second column. My code works it is just very slow as the number of rows reaches 500k. Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ['tom', 0], 
    ['nick', 1], 
    ['juli', 2],
    ['tom', 3], 
    ['nick', 1], 
    ['juli', 2],
    ['tom', 1], 
    ['nick', 0], 
    ['juli', 1],
    ['tom', 3], 
    ['nick', 2], 
    ['juli', 2],
    ['tom', 2], 
    ['nick', 0], 
    ['juli', 0],
    ['tom', 1], 
    ['nick', 1], 
    ['juli', 1]
] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'moves'])
```

`df`:

```
    name  moves
0    tom      0
1   nick      1
2   juli      2
3    tom      3
4   nick      1
5   juli      2
6    tom      1
7   nick      0
8   juli      1
9    tom      3
10  nick      2
11  juli      2
12   tom      2
13  nick      0
14  juli      0
15   tom      1
16  nick      1
17  juli      1
```

What I've tried:

```
movement_data=np.zeros((len(df.name.unique()),4))

for u in df.name.unique():
    name_data=df[df.name==u]
    i=0
    movement_data[i][
        name_data.moves.value_counts().index.values
    ]=name_data.moves.value_counts().values
    print(u,movement_data[i,:])
    i=i+1
```

This outputs:

```
tom [1. 2. 1. 2.]
nick [2. 3. 1. 2.]
juli [1. 2. 3. 2.]
```

I have seen several posts on the isin function however I am not sure how it could be applied to this use case.

Comment: `df.groupby('name')['moves'].value_counts()` this is basically what you are doing

Comment: Maybe you can try dask or modin to speedup pandas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dask replicate Pandas value counts on Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45442832/dask-replicate-pandas-value-counts-on-groupby)